# Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader' during startup registration

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, castle-windsor

When you create new `Xamarin.Forms` project using .NET Standard, install `Castle Windsor` and run the project on `Android` it will fail with the following error

```
D/Mono    ( 5829): Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Runtime.Loader'.
F/monodroid-assembly( 5829): Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader' during startup registration.
F/monodroid-assembly( 5829): This might be due to an invalid debug installation.
F/monodroid-assembly( 5829): A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE.
```

When I opened properties of the Android project and changed linking to `Sdk and User assemblies` the application ran as expected. I thought the linking option can only introduce problems as some codes won't be included, yet it fixes it.

Also, one thing to note, the previous project I worked on uses `Reference` whereas the newly created project uses `PackageReference` for nuget packages.

**UPDATE:** The project suddenly stopped working, removing `Castle Windsor` and/or changing linking options had no effect.

I did try clearing solution, nuget cache and building/running the project on different devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving back to `packages.config` nuget management fixed the problem.