# using signalr client with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` on Xamarin forms (on .net standard 2.0) and run the android app. I keep getting the error

> Could not load assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions' during startup registration

I have tried installing System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions nuget's latest prerelease, I still get the same error. I did not find any one else with this issue online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Visual Studio 2017 Update **15.8** + [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) Package with at [least Version 1.0.1](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/305)

> ASP.NET Core 2.1.1 contains fixes to resolve blocking issues when
>   using the SignalR Client from Xamarin. However, these fixes also
>   require an updated build of Xamarin.iOS and **Xamarin.Android**, as
>   well as some additional dependencies.
>
> In order to use the SignalR Client in Xamarin applications you will
>   need to:
>
> ```
> Upgrade Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client to 1.0.1. 
> Upgrade Xamarin to the appropriate version:
>     Xamarin.Android 8.4.0.1
> ```

VS2017 Update 15.8 comes with Xamarin.Android 9.0.x tools which contains the fix for the issue.

Comment: thanks. it also works with older versions of visual studio

Comment: with the suggestion from Lex, i had created a git issue https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1518. after this the bug(s) were resolved.

Comment: for me it failed in 15.7 with error [System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2037). I also had to [switch to packages.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48824785/1466046) to get it fully working in 15.8.

Comment: the file not found could be fixed by adding some nugets. i had created a couple of xamarin apps with signalr before 15.8

Comment: no, this was a bug with the xamarin.android tools and is fixed with 15.8

Comment: true it was a bug on 15.7.x. But it had hotfixes and I have working xamarin forms + android + signalr core projects using vs 15.7.x

Comment: well i had to apply a couple of fixes

Comment: I wish people would get out of the habit of talking about Visual Studio release numbers; dotnet is trying really hard (failing miserably, of course) to not be Windows-centric.

Comment: @JamesMoore but some features require a special VS version update to work.